# Css hover image transition acting weird

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure out why the hover image is flying from the left to bottom with transition effect even though the hover image is only set to padding-bottom. I just want the hover image to appear at the bottom of the menu when hovered.

http://jsfiddle.net/9buk14b5/1/

```
<header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">
        <nav id="primary_nav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Get a Quote</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

#primary_nav ul{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    li{
        float: left;
        padding: 15px 50px 15px 0;
        a{
        color:#ccc;
            &:hover{
                color:#fff;
                background: url('../images/hover.png') no-repeat;
                background-position: center center;
                width: 22px;
                height: 19px;
                padding-bottom: 35px;
                -webkit-transition: 0.8s all ease-out;
                -o-transition: 0.8s all ease-out;
                -moz-transition: 0.8s all ease-out;
                transition: 0.8s all ease-out;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the `:after` pseudo-element in conjunction with `:hover`.

```
li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 15px 50px 15px 0;
    
    a {
        padding-bottom: 35px;
        
        &:after {
            position: absolute;
            content: '';
            bottom: -3px;
            left: 25%;
            display:block;
            margin: 0 -11px;
            background: url('http://i60.tinypic.com/35a7xvs.png') no-repeat 0;
            width: 22px;
            height: 19px;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 500ms linear;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
            -moz-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
            -ms-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
            -o-transition: opacity 200ms linear;
        }
        
        &:hover {
            &:after {
            opacity: 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add the `background-image` to the `:after` pseudo element allows you to set a style to applied when its parent `<a>` is hovered. In this case, we set the pseudo element to`opacity:0;` initially and `opacity:1;`, then we simply set the `transition-property` to watch `opacity`.

#### Fade in/Fade out Examples:

- Fiddle using original background image: http://jsfiddle.net/9buk14b5/8/
- Fiddle using only css to create triangle: http://jsfiddle.net/9buk14b5/7/

---

<strike>A few things:</strike>

The odd animation behavior is fixed by tell the `transition` which property to animate. In your code it's set to `all`. Change that to `padding`. I've also changed the timing function to be `ease-in-out`.

```
-webkit-transition: 0.8s padding ease-in-out;
-o-transition: 0.8s padding ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: 0.8s padding ease-in-out;
transition: 0.8s padding ease-in-out;
```

Second, your `padding-bottom` amount needs to be the sum of the height of the element it is trying to go to the bottom of, and any padding, border, margin offset it may include. In your case, the magic number was `132px`

```
padding-bottom: 132px;
```

Here is a working fiddle with these modifications: http://jsfiddle.net/rv9wbn8b/

Edit:

To show the arrow without any effect, simply move the `padding` outside of the `:hover`

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9buk14b5/4/

Comment: Sorry I probably didn't make my post clear, I just want the hover to appear at the bottom without dropping effect or anything, if you remove the transition you'll see what I meant. As for the padding the height of the header is just a random height therefore my padding 35px is just the right amount on my actual site. Rather how can I position the hover image at the bottom without padding? I tried margin-bottom but that didn't work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9buk14b5/3/ here is the hover without the transition effect, which how I wanted but with the transition effect.

Comment: I've already accomplished that without the transition effect, but I want to apply a transition effect. Okay lets just say I want the hover image to fadein when you hovered on the link. Its like when you have a colour transition effect on the link but with the arrow below it. Aha I think I'm not making sense anymore here :/